# shown.bs.modal, show.bs.modal, hidden.bs.modal won't fire on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am fallen into a very weird problem that I had never faced before. What I am doing is that I am handling the bootstrap `show.bs.modal/shown.bs.modal` and `hidden.bs.modal` events so that I could tweak my CSS a bit when a modal is opened and closed. On desktop it runs just fine but when I try to open the website on mobile it doesn't handle those on mobile.

Here is my code: [MyWebsite](http://projects.hassanfarid.com/ReaderProject/home.html)

```
$('.bs-example-modal-lg').bind('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $("html").css("overflow", "visible");
});
$('.bs-example-modal-lg').bind('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    $("html").css("overflow", "hidden");
});
```

Here's the [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/tfAf6/4/). Better watch the results [here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/tfAf6/4/show/).

Comment: Where are your events being declared?

Comment: @RobSchmuecker Are you asking about the file?

Comment: Well yes.  We have little other information to go on and I'm not going to waste time going through all the JS files on your page!

Comment: @RobSchmuecker I am really very sorry, let me post the JS code of declaration of events.

Comment: @RobSchmuecker I edited the post, you could see it now. :)

Comment: Strange.  Seems to work for me in an "emulator" on chrome? what device are you testing on?  Also a fiddle will make it easier to debug by others.  It shouldn't be buggy at all, you just need to absolutely reference the files/images/css to your server.

Comment: @RobSchmuecker I am trying on Moto G.

Comment: OK - Moto G, what Browser and fiddle so we can hack and help!

Comment: @RobSchmuecker Here's the fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/tfAf6/4/show/.

Comment: This works on my galaxy ace http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/tfAf6/5/embedded/result/